# Is WSL2 default enabled for insiders (after 1909 update)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have downloaded the latest Windows update version 1909 available to me with the new Windows Terminal (Preview) and opted in for the Insiders program, Slow ring which apparently now has the WSL2 stuff too. I properly set up everything and enabled WSL with Ubuntu build but I am not 100% that I am running WSL v2. The commands I find online such as: `wsl -l -v` or `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` just don't exist. The "manpage" contains only the following:

```
Arguments to run Linux binaries:

    If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.

    --exec, -e <CommandLine>
        Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.

    --
        Pass the remaining command line as is.

Options:
    --distribution, -d <DistributionName>
        Run the specified distribution.

    --user, -u <UserName>
        Run as the specified user.

Arguments to manage Windows Subsystem for Linux:

    --export <DistributionName> <FileName>
        Exports the distribution to a tar file.
        The filename can be - for standard output.

    --import <DistributionName> <InstallLocation> <FileName>
        Imports the specified tar file as a new distribution.
        The filename can be - for standard input.

    --list, -l [Options]
        Lists distributions.

        Options:
            --all
                List all distributions, including distributions that are currently
                being installed or uninstalled.

            --running
                List only distributions that are currently running.

    -setdefault, -s <DistributionName>
        Sets the distribution as the default.

    --terminate, -t <DistributionName>
        Terminates the distribution.

    --unregister <DistributionName>
        Unregisters the distribution.

    --upgrade <DistributionName>
        Upgrades the distribution to the WslFs file system format.

    --help
        Display usage information.
```

I was able to install the *Remote VSCode extension* on my Visual Studio Code which I think is a WSL2 thing though which is what makes me think that they have moved everything to WSL2 version.

Any clarifications?

Comment: "Slow ring which apparently now has the WSL2 stuff too." - 1909 itself has WSL2.  Any version after 1909 would also support WSL2.  What build exactly are you running?  Submit a screenshot that shows what Windows Features you have enabled.

Comment: A simple test -- Is `wsl.exe --help` command has `--set-version` and `--set-default-version` option? If no then no WSL2.

Comment: Provide the output of `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VirtualMachinePlatform` as a screenshot.  Can you also include the output of `wsl --list --verbose` as a screenshot

Comment: " ... Visual Studio Code which I think is a WSL2" - Support for WSL2 is experimental but it's also not required.  You have yet to perform the step to set the version.

Comment: @Ramhound As I said in my question the `--verbose` command **doesn't** exist. It prints the manpage which I have posted above. winver shows version 1909 build 18363.535

Comment: @Konstantine - I would still like to see the error for myself.  So I would like you to attempt the command then provide a screenshot of the error message.  I thought you were using an Insider Preview build?  `18363.535` is the current 1909 build and is not considered to be an Insider Preview build.  Will also need to know which features you have enabled.  I would appreciate you simply provide the information instead of submitting a comment, if you can't provide the information, don't do anything.  After 24 hours I will just delete my comments, but without knowing specifics, I can't help.

Comment: I would also run these commands from a PowerShell command prompt instead of Windows Terminal.

Comment: I found the problem, I was just not in the insider build. I had opted in but for some reason it did not properly upgrade and of course, having WSL1 it would not provide any related information for WSL2.